# Android - Blinking image using the Alpha fade animation

Tags: android, fadein

I've been struggling for a few days on this, finally just decided to ask. It's so simple I've got to be missing something very basic.

I have an XML layout page with an image defined.  I have two anim XML pages, one to change alpha from 0 to 1, and the other from 1 to 0 in order to create a "blinking" effect. So the alphaAnimation is defined in XML, I just need to call it.

The image pops up, but there's no looping blinking effect.

```
public class blinker extends Activity {

   //create name of animation
Animation myFadeInAnimation;
Animation myFadeOutAnimation;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scanning_view);

 //grab the imageview and load the animations
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blinkingView01); 
    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.fade_in);
    Animation myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.fade_out);

//fade it in, and fade it out. 
    myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
    myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation);
     }
}
```

Two XML Animation layouts in Anim resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="50" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
 </set>
```

And the other:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="1000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
</set>
```

Comment: Hi Charlie, love your show man.  :)  I edited original post, added in the two XML files (fade_in.xml and fade_out.xml)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Why not use `android:repeatMode="reverse"`

Comment: Still same issue.  Screen appears, but no animation.

Comment: Why is your first parameter null instead of this in: nimationUtils.loadAnimation(null,... ?

Comment: that was yet another iteration, I've been through so many, including another complete rewrite to animate the image. Originally I stipulated "this".

Comment: I needed a break to rest sore eyes.  I implemented two things after reading through responses Methodin, and I have it working now.  Many thanks.

Comment: Methodin, too many hours at the screen and keyboard. :)  The iteration aboved worked when I went back to "this".  I decided not to use repeatMode="reverse" just so I could have more granualar control over the fade in and fade out speeds since each can be set independently of each other.  Fast fade in, slow fade out by example.

Answer (score 107):

The best way to tween fade :

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 
Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Splash.this, R.anim.tween);
myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
```

in your res/anim/ create tween.xml tween 1s start opacity 0 to 1 and reverse infinit...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />
</set>
```

Comment: It worked for me !! I have kept fromAlpha as 0.2 so that the view does not disappear completely. Thanks Buchs, +1 for this.

Comment: For me, it only repeats once: in and out. Then it does nothing.

Comment: @brainmurphy1 maybe you forgot `android:repeatCount="infinite"`. The repeat count needs to be positive or infinite.

Comment: Code is working good. But I want to set this animation on a timer, so it should be blink per second. But due to fading, it is taking more time that a second. I change the duration from 1000 to 500, 600 & and so on. But cant get exact timing. Can you please help me to know what will be the value of duration in the case of a timer?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the below alpha animation to set the blinking effects to the views in android.

```
blinkanimation= new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
blinkanimation.setDuration(300); // duration
blinkanimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
blinkanimation.setRepeatCount(3); // Repeat animation infinitely
blinkanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

After this add the animation to your view like,

```
view.setAnimation(blinkanimation);
```

or

```
view.startAnimation(blinkanimation);
```

Comment: how to change duration in this method?

Comment: Change it in blinkanimation.setDuration(your duration); @Hamid

Comment: LinearInterpolator is default one, no need to explicitly set it

Comment: doesn't infinite animations have `-1` as repeat count ?

Comment: @natinusala yes it is.  `anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);` or `...(-1);`

Answer (score 8):

If someone will decide to use programmatic version:

```
val anim = AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f)
anim.duration = 750
anim.fillAfter = true  

// here is repeat settings
anim.repeatMode = AlphaAnimation.REVERSE // ping pong mode
anim.repeatCount = 1 // count of repeats

yourView.startAnimation(anim)
```