# Blink circle with thread and handler but impossible to stop it

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I develop an application and I want to make a circle blink when you click on a button. I have 8 circle on my view and I want them blinking separatly. I use this code :

```
public void blink(final View id, final int position, final boolean bool) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();   
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int timeToBlink = 250;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if (id.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                id.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                id.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        blink(id,position,true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        th.setName(Integer.toString(position));
        aThread.add(th);
        th.start();
```

where id is the id of the circle

but I can't stop blink with th.interupt

anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Add a boolean variable to block the recursive blink call in the thread.

Comment: I test this but not work

Comment: Why cant you try with animation? when u done with blinking you can cleat the blink animation with clearAnimation();
Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852281/android-how-can-i-make-a-button-flash

Comment: How many times do you want it to blink? You are just running a loop by calling it again within the Runnable so it will continue to blink nonstop.

Comment: @jibysthomas i will see this link thanks.
i want it blink until that push a button to stop it

Comment: This surely help you i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906738/android-blinking-image-using-the-alpha-fade-animation

Comment: why my question vote down ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @jibysthomas i fixe my problem i use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852281/android-how-can-i-make-a-button-flash) and i made this :

```
final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); 
        animation.setDuration(250); // duration - half a second
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); 
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); 
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

and i call this annimation on my circle.

Thanks a lot to jibysthomas