# How to run two or more animation in order (one by one) in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want run **alpha animation** from **1** to **0** first, and **after** I want to run **alpha animation** from **0** to **1**, but it ***doesn't work***!
this is my code:

```
TextView iv_1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
AnimationSet animSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_set);
iv_1.setAnimation(animSet);
```

**alpha_set.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true"
>

    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="1"
           android:toAlpha="0"
    />

    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="0"
           android:toAlpha="1"
           android:startOffset="2000"/>

</set>
```

but when I want run **alpha animation** first, and after run **scale animation**, it ***works well***! Below is my code:

```
TextView iv_1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
AnimationSet animSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_and_scale);
iv_1.setAnimation(animSet);
```

**alpha_and_scale.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true">

    <alpha android:duration="2000"
           android:fromAlpha="0"
           android:toAlpha="1"
    />
    <scale android:startOffset="2000"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:fromXScale="0.8"
           android:toXScale="1"
           android:fromYScale="1"
           android:toYScale="1"
           android:duration="2000"/>

</set>
```

why?

Comment: you can use animation listeners as a workaround. Or just use animation repeat count (2) and repeat mode (reverse) to just repeat the animation

Comment: thank you for your help! but it can't solve my problem

Comment: I see no single reason why it could not.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko could you try to run my code in your device?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following and it works for me.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="1"/>
</set>
```

I followed [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821128/8159810) Hope this helps you.